# Specific class instead of generics in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, hashmap

How can I extend HashMap with a specific class.

```
public class TestMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V>
```

I want V to be an Integer. Writing Integer instead of V overrides Integer class and causes bugs(`Integer i = 1` does not work) when integer is used. How can I fix this?n

Comment: Integer i = 1 does work, can you show whats not working for you?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Presumably they were trying to do `TestMap<K, Integer> ...` which hides `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi what Radiodef is saying is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameterize the extended class and only declare a type for the key:

```
class IntegerMap<K> extends HashMap<K, Integer> {}
```

Then you can do:

```
IntegerMap<String> integerByString = new IntegerMap<String>();
integerByString.put("0", 0);
integerByString.put("1", 1);
```

As a side note, if you are actually extending a JDK collection class, it is generally not considered a good style.

Normally you would write a class that controls the Map from the outside:

```
class MapController<K> {
    Map<K, Integer> theMap;
}
```

Or perhaps a method that prepares it in some way:

```
static <K> Map<K, Integer> prepMap() {
    Map<K, Integer> theMap = new HashMap<>();
    return theMap;
}
```

Comment: This is probably a bad idea.  See e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02216/

Comment: It works. Thanks. Now I can get rid of those pesky `(Integer)` casts and what not.